# Why do I see sporadic Application_Start calls, but no intervening Application_End?

Tags: asp.net, iis-10

So after much reading about Application_Start and _End, and their relationship to the application pool and http lifecycle, I'm still confused.  I added logging to both (Global.asax) Applicaton_Start and Application_End (which does Not write locally or modify the config file).  I see this logging working properly if I (for example) go into IIS and change a parameter: I'll see a _End being logged, followed quickly by a _Start.  Great.  BUT, my "problem" is that I see SPORADIC logging of Application_Start calls (sometimes a couple per day, sometimes a couple days apart).  These don't Seem to correlate to specific HTTP Request activity that I see logged in the IIS Logs (per timestamps).  I'm Less concerned about the _Start/_End mismatch than I am about the multiple _Starts.   I'm thinking this is somehow related to Application Pool settings, but I'm in the dark.

Comment: @Lex Li - I'm happy to go off and "read more", but w.r.t. your comment, I specifically stated that I see SPORADIC events, NOT events occurring at "specific time spots".   Additionally, from all I'm able to see, no correlation exists to either incoming HTTP request activity OR IIS parameter manipulation.  So, do you have specific, helpful suggestions as to how I might efficiently diagnose this issue?

Comment: ETW can get you started https://www.tessferrandez.com/blog/2008/11/06/troubleshooting-appdomain-restarts-and-other-issues-with-ETW-tracing.html if that's what you are actually after.

Comment: Your spider sense that this may well be app pool restarting is likely the issue.  App pool will recycle often due to un handled errors,  and also on it's own